# JavaScript/Ajax - Send Data and Receive response with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my JavaScript code for sending the post action:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ColorId = "1";
    $( "#targetButton" ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'checkcolors.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var arr = data.msg.split(',');
                    arr.forEach(function(id){
                        $('#' + id.trim()).hide();
                    });
                    //$('#target').html(data.msg);
                },
                data: ColorId
            });
    });     

}); 
</script>
<button type="button" id="targetButton">Send</button>
<div style="BlackAndWhite" id="24604682">24604682</div>
<div style="BlackAndWhite" id="24604682x">24604682x</div>
<div style="BlackAndWhite" id="24604679">24604679</div>
<div style="BlackAndWhite" id="24604621">24604621</div>
```

Here are the results from checkcolors.php:

```
24604603, 24604684, 24604640, 24604609, 24604682, 24604686, 24604681, 24604689, 24604602, 24604679, 24604680, 24604622, 24604685, 24604683, 24604621, 24604677, 24604688,
```

I can make them to be printed like this also:

```
24604603
24604684
24604640
24604609
24604682
24604686
24604681
24604689
24604602
24604679
24604680
24604622
24604685
24604683
24604621
24604677
24604688
```

I can make these numbers to be formated however i want.

**What i have to do!**

I have html div elements with the same `ids` that the result is returning.
When these numbers are returned i have to hide all div elements with the ids shown from checkcolors.php response.

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Return a JSON object instead: [PHP json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Can you please show me how with code example as a answer to this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could, yes, but you'll feel so much better about yourself once you read the documentation and solve the problem on your own. Have fun!

Comment: I learn best from working example. I do not get it at all from these links. Thanks anyway. I'll wait :)

Comment: It would be ideal to have a JSON object with an array returned but you could also split the string and then hide/show the divs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very crude way to do it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        var person = {
            name: $("#id-name").val(),
            address:$("#id-address").val(),
            phone:$("#id-phone").val()
        }

        $('#target').html('sending..');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkcolors.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = data.msg.split(',');
                arr.forEach(function(id){
                    $('#' + id.trim()).hide();
                });
                //$('#target').html(data.msg);
            },
            data: person
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please add it to the code from the question and make it as a complete answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please see the updated question because somehow it is not working. Thanks :)

Comment: Open up the Javascript Console and check if there's any other errors.

Answer (score -1):

Why style="BlackAndWhite" can be a class="BlackAndWhite" ???

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ColorId = "1";
    $( "#targetButton" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkcolors.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var arr = data.split(',');
                var html = "";
                arr.forEach(function(id){
                    html += "<div style='BlackAndWhite' id='" + id + "'>" + id + "</div>";
                });
                $('#target').html(html);
            },
            data: ColorId
        });
    });     

}); 
</script>
<button type="button" id="targetButton">Send</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```